# declare really large array with default value in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I want to declare 6 big array with the length of 64800 of int value.
i am declaring the array as:

```
int item_value_1[64800] = {0,5,10, ...,1025 };
```

in the header file. 
The compiler shows no error but it take really long time to load and compile.

What is the best way to load these arrays? I am mostly interested in a quick load time.

Comment: That should not take a really long time to run. Could you provide a [Minimum example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so we can see the context?

Comment: _to load and compile_ you don’t know what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a small dynamic array first and then increase it as per the need.
It will help your program to load and execute faster.